# How to avoid empty space at the end of a page when using scrlttr2?

Tags: spacing, koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I use this class definition in the preamble for typesetting letters:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,foldmarks=true,fromalign=right,fromrule=afteraddress,
  parskip=half, pagenumber=no,DIV=15]{scrlttr2}

%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=0cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
```

I have to struggle with the general problem that latex compiles into a letter with 2 pages. On the first page the last third is just empty. On the second page there is only the closing preceded by the last line of the last paragraph. It's ugly and wastes a lot of paper.

I mean, there is no point in only printing the signature  on a new page.

Do you have the same problem and how do I get around that?

Comment: While the class option `enlargefirstpage=true` has a positive effect here, it’s still limited by `footskip`, which it respects. Then setting `\setlength{\footskip}{0mm}` has an additional effect, but affects every other page as well, not just the first one. So, instead, an explicit `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` in addition to the implicit one caused by the class option seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With `scrlttr2` I sometimes used `\enlargethispage` as a quick way to get more text onto the first page, for example:

```
\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}
```

Done before the end of the letter or before the end of the first page, respectively, this allows three further lines on the page. There's even a starred version `\enlargethispage*` which tries also compression.

Alternatively, you could use the option `enlargefirstpage=true` which increases the text area if the footer of the first page doesn't use much space, or adjust the pseudolength `firstfootvpos` or use `typearea` package features. I quickly took the easy first way, depending on my letter's size. The other ways are described in the KOMA-Script manual.

Comment: I had read about \enlargethispage, enlargefirstpage=true and firstfootvpos beforehand. I was not sure which one would be the 'cleanest' way to achieve my goal. "enlargefirstpage=true" and "\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}" each seem to do the job in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

A combination of the options `enlargefirstpage` and `firstfoot=false` is a very easy solution to enlarge the first page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fromalign=right,fromrule=afteraddress,
               parskip=half,pagenumber=no,DIV=15,
               enlargefirstpage,firstfoot=false]{scrlttr2}
```

I've removed option `foldmarks=true`, because it's default. All other options are unchanged from the question.

To see the difference of using the two options as show above, compare the left and right picture:

[image]

The right one has been made with:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,fromalign=right,fromrule=afteraddress,
  parskip=half,pagenumber=no,DIV=15,
  enlargefirstpage,firstfoot=false
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
  \opening{Hey!}
  \blindtext[5]
  \closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

the left one without line

```
  enlargefirstpage,firstfoot=false
```

BTW: Even

```
  enlargefirstpage,firstfoot=yes
```

would result in a little bit more text on the first page:

[image]

so the comment, that `firstfoot=yes` would result in errors is not true. However, if you really want more text on the first page, I would recommend to use `firstfoot=false` as originally stated.

Comment: These options do not work.  I explicitly get errors when using firstfoot=yes

Comment: @cryptic0 These options do work (from KOMA-Script 2.98, released 4½ years before your comment)! However setting `firstfoot=false` is part of the answer and `firstfoot=yes` would be the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

I created an invoice with `srlttr2` and on DIN-A4 paper. Had some hours struggling around with the recommendations (`enlargefirstpage`, `firstfoot=false`), but without success.

Then I set:

```
  \setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
  \setlength{\footskip}{0mm}
  \setlength{\footheight}{0mm}
```

With `textheight` I can expand the text area to the bottom of the page. That was what I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.