# koma-scrlttr2: bottom margin is immense, how to reduce?

Tags: margins, koma-script, letters

I'm really struggling with what seems like it should be a simple layout question for KOMA scrlttr2.

I simply cannot find any way to get the bottom margin of a letter to be anything less than 2 inches. I've browsed through the KOMA documentation. I certainly understand the authors' wish for users to understand the principles of proper page layout for publication. However, a letter is *not for publication*. A bottom margin of 2-3 cm may be too small for publication, but it's entirely reasonable for a letter.

So I think it should be a fairly simple question, but the documentation provides pounds of theory but nothing like a simple answer.

First I tried the geometry package, but the "bottom" property had no effect. Scrlttr2 still insists on breaking the page about 2 inches above the page boundary.

Then I saw that typearea is recommended for KOMA scripts. The width parameter of \areaset clearly takes effect, but the height parameter does not.

```
\usepackage[headexclude,footexclude,landscape]{typearea}
\areaset{6.5in}{11in}
```

I'm sure there must be a way to do this. There's plenty of room on the page for the content. It's just that scrlttr2 is refusing to let me use that space.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does this question/answer help: [How to remove space between back address and address in scrlttr2?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109797/how-to-remove-space-between-back-address-and-address-in-scrlttr2/109855#109855)

Comment: I have no problems to get text until the bottom margin - neither with `\areaset` no `geometry`. You should make a complete example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Marco: Thanks, but no, it doesn't help. My question referred to page margins, but nothing about the address or backaddress.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default there is space on the first page for a footer.  You can turn this off with the class option `firstfoot=false`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[firstfoot=false]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\areaset{6.5in}{11in}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{addressee}

\opening{Dear XXX}
\lipsum[1-20]
\closing{Yours}
\end{letter}


\end{document}
```

As mentioned in comments there is additionally an `enlargefirstpage` option that can be used in the documentclass in addition to `firstfoot=false`, but I have yet to see any concrete example where this makes a difference.

A brute force way to get extra space on the first page is by writing e.g. `\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}` just before the `\opening` command.  However, this will not respect your original page boundaries and should only be used in an emergency situation.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try a bit later this morning. Actually I'm using scrlttr2 by way of org-mode export, which supports a #+DOCUMENT_CLASS_OPTIONS line for such settings.

Comment: I believe, in some cases, you need in addition to `firstfoot=false` also `enlargefirstpage` as another documentclass option as well as something like `\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}` after `opening{}`. See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17599/166599).