# How to fit a large text on one page using scrlttr2?

Tags: koma-script, letters

**EDIT: During the comments I noted that I should not try to change the top margin manually to keep the DIN - therefore my question is now only how can I reduce font size without changing the right and left margin.**

---

I try to write a covering letter with scrlttr2. My goal is to fit my text on one page. I have found the following tricks to gain more space:

I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146668/koma-scrlttr2-bottom-margin-is-immense-how-to-reduce) that one can reduce the bottom margin with the class option:

```
firstfoot=false
```

I also found that I can reduce the top-margin with:

```
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}
```

I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183783/how-can-i-reduce-top-margin-in-scrlttr2) that I could reduce the top-margin further with

```
\setkomavar{fromname}{%
\vspace{-\useplength{firstheadvpos}}%
Me, I  and myself}
```

but it didnt work for me.

I thought as a final step I could reduce the fontsize. But whenever I reduce the fontsize, the left and right margin becomes larger. How can I change the fontsize without changing the margin, or what else can I do to gain more space for my text?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[%
    max-mustermann,
    fromlogo=false,
    enlargefirstpage,
    fontsize=12pt,
    parskip=on,
    firstfoot=false]
{scrlttr2}
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomavar{subject}{My applicationn}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Mr. Max,Maxstreet 5, 10715 Berlin}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Musterunternehmen\\ Musterstraße 12\\
12345 Musterstadt}
\opening{Hello everyone,}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\Blindtext
\closing{Best regards,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, letters are standardized to match certain criteria, for example fit into a windowed envelope. Is this a limitation for you or do you *just want to get something lettery out there*?

Comment: Try playing around with high (20) `DIV` values. To be honest, this will soon look ugly and unprofessional.

Comment: @Johannes_B is the letter stil standardizes if I use DINmtext? Well of couse it would be better if I could leave the top-margin standardized and just make the left and right margin smaller of the text.

Comment: According to the documentation, this `lco` is to get more content on the page and using a different folding to still fit the envelopes.

Comment: If the letter shall still fit, use the `DIV` method mentioned above. If there are no restrictions, i would have suggested the same as in @Werner's answer.

Comment: The left and right margins are calculated in dependence of the fontsize to a given amount of glyphs per line. This is to ensure the readability of the text, which is highest for about 66 glyphs. You can control the margins by increasing `DIV`. Try a ridiculously high value of 80.

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you that worked for me. If you post your comment as an answer, I will check it.

Comment: You can post it as an answer yourself, if you prefer not to, just give me a hint, i'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure you want to read this.

KOMA-Script gives you a good typographic letter with in your case german rules.  For example it gives the adress the right position so that you can simply use a windowed envelope to send the letter.
With option `DINmtext` you can't use a windowed envelope.

I can not see a relevant reason to give up this automatic.

So if you not have to use the german (or other) rules for a letter you can use each document class you want, for example follow @werner answer.

If you have to follow the rules use KOMA-Script with the usual behaving and accept to get two pages or make your text shorter, if possible.

If you insist in changing the font size (use option `fontsize=10pt`, I would not use a smaller one!) but using the given margins you can use package `geometry`, for example set right and left margin to 1 cm:

```
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: You are right, one should probably keep the DIN. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest avoiding a document class that restricts you such freedom. For that, set the letter using the (ordinary) `article` document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\underline{Mr.\ Max, Maxstreet 5, 10715 Berlin}

\bigskip

Musterunternehmen \\
Musterstraße 12 \\
12345 Musterstadt

\bigskip

\hfill\today

\bigskip

\textbf{My application}

\bigskip

Hello everyone,

\medskip

\blindtext
\blindtext
\Blindtext
\blindtext

\medskip

Best regards,

\bigskip

Author

\end{document}
```

Perhaps there are some minor differences between your output under KOMA-Script, but the modifications are fairly straight-forward and easy to manipulate. I've just made a quick mock-up, so it can form a base for what you're after.